# Event when TTL is expired

Tags: node.js, redis

Does Redis emit any kind of event when the TTL expires for a particular key?

I am looking to have a count of keys added in Redis for my application at any given point of time. I am having a increment counter when I am generating the key, similarly I would like to have a decrement counter when the key expires (TTL expires).
I know I can acheive this by executing 'KEYS', but I am wondering if Redis generates some kind of event which I can capture when key expires. 
I will use NodeJS to capture the event.

Thanks,
Raghu.

Comment: Yes, see  the documentation at http://redis.io/topics/notifications

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use `KEYS` in production** - it is a potentially long-running, RAM-consuming, service-denying operation.

Yes, as of v2.8.0 Redis does have what you're looking for. Read the [Redis Keyspace Notifications](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) page, specifically about setting up the `x` flag and subscribing to relevant channels.

Note that while this is a great way to use Redis, PubSub messages' delivery is **not guaranteed** so your counters could shift over time if messages are lost. In this case it would probably be good to periodically scan your database (using the `SCAN` command, **not `KEYS`**) to refresh them.